# is it possible to detect fake touch in android/ios?

Tags: android, ios, interface, touch, detection

Is it possible to detect in android/ios system whether the screen is touched (touch/swipe etc) by a human or fake touch event (programmatically generated touch) ?

Comment: If you're the one generating the fake touch, maybe you can give yourself a flag with the touches you generate

Comment: You could check if the device is connected to a USB, and maybe if the device is debuggable. This could give you a hint if the touches are originated from the PC. However, the user can also do it by using Root...

Comment: @androiddeveloper what if the android runs on a VM ?

Comment: @aroyc You mean the emulator? You can detect that too. Question is, if that's enough for you.

Comment: @androiddeveloper thanks for your reply...actually I'm interested to towards the general problem. Your solutions will work for these special cases but I need for the other cases too !!

Comment: @aroyc That's what I thought, which is why I kept writing it in the comments. I don't think there is a solution for this, but it could be nice to know that for sure.